# Java: JFrame and subclasses

Tags: java, jframe, polymorphism, jlayeredpane

Alright, so basically I'm trying to make a text-based game in java using JFrame, and eventually some other simple components. My main problem is that I've created a few subclasses, Text being one of them. I need Text to be a subclass because it needs to access the JLayeredPane (layer) directly. My problem is that every time I create a new Text, or any other subclass, and try to run the program, a bunch of windows repeatedly pop up. Now I've come to realize that is probably because using Text calls Launcher and this viscous cycle starts. Now I know I'm no java wizard which is why I'm curious as to if anyone has a solution of any type to this?

My parent class:

```
package Game;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;

public class Launcher
{   
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Game");
    public JLayeredPane layer = frame.getLayeredPane ();

    public Launcher ()
    {
        frame.setTitle ("Game");
        frame.setVisible (true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize (906, 629);
        frame.setResizable (false);//To be changed at a later point when I feel like adding the functionality
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);

        Text test = new Text ("This here will cause an error", 0, 0);//It doesnt matter where you put this because even if it were to go into a subclass (which is where it would go), even a call to that would perpetuate this evil loop
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Launcher run = new Launcher ();
    }
}
```

My sub-class:

```
package Game;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Text extends Panel
{
    private JLabel text;
    private int x, y;
    private int across;
    private int tall;

    private String font;
    private int style;
    private int size;

    private boolean updated;

    public Text (String text, int x, int y, int across, int tall, String font, int style, int size)//More or less for buttons
    {   
        this.text = new JLabel (text);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.across = across;
        this.tall = tall;

        this.font = font;
        this.style = style;
        this.size = size;

        updated = true;
    }

    public Text (String text, int x, int y, String font, int style, int size)
    {
        this (text, x, y, 900, 600, font, style, size);
    }

    public Text (String text, int x, int y)
    {
        this (text, x, y, 900, 600, "Bakerville Old Font", Font.PLAIN, 16);
    }

    public void add ()
    {
        text.setFont (new Font (font, style, size));
        text.setBounds (x, y, across, tall);
        layer.add (text, new Integer (3));

        layer.repaint();

        updated = true;
    }

    public void remove ()
    {
        layer.remove (text);
    }
}
```

Comment: To stat with `Text ` should be extend from `JPanel` - mind you, since you never add it to anything, it doesn't really need to extend from anything :P

Comment: I don't have an issue, I get a single frame - admittedly it "moves quickly" from one position to another when it's first opened, which can be fixed by calling `setVisible` last

Comment: Yes, moving setVisable to the end stopped it from moving, but it hasn't stopped multiple windows. And how would extending JPanel help me add different variations of text to the same panel within my one JFrame? I don't really see the fix with that extension.

Comment: First - Your example doesn't generate multiple windows, it only generates one - so we can't help you with that. Second, `Panel` is a heavy weight, AWT based, component, which doesn't play very well with Swing - to start with it's opaque and you can't change it, second, it doesn't support Swing's concept of Z-Ordering. Having said all that, you're not actually making any use of it's functionality, so you don't actually need it, `Text` simply doesn't need to extend from anything, based on your example